# Postman with AWS signature: Missing x-amz-target Header

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, amazon-cloudfront

I am using postman interceptor to mimic a request happening before the user logs in the application, that request happens successfully on the browser but when using postman the server throws the error `Missing x-amz-target Header`

When I compare the request from the browser vs the one from postman, they're identical:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it included in `SignedHeaders` in `Authorization`?  That isn't visible.